# Phonegap navigator.notification.alert callback is not working with cordova2.1.0 for Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an android application using cordova2.1.0 and in this I am using navigator.notification.alert with a callback function on clicking Ok button of the alert. I am getting the alert pop up but the callback function is not getting called on clicking 'Ok'. I got it working using cordova2.0.0 version but is not working in cordova2.1.0. Please help me. Code I am using is as follows:

```
  function WriteReviewAlert(){
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Alert message.',  // message
             gotoSettings,         // callback
            'Test',            //title
            'OK'                  // buttonName
        );
}


  function gotoSettings()
{
    $.mobile.changePage( 'settings.html', { transition: "slide"} );
}
```

Comment: could you please update with code..

Answer (score 1):

Check this it may help you..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Notification Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            // PhoneGap is ready       
            function onDeviceReady() {

            }

        function onConfirm(button) {
            alert('...');
        }

                function showConfirm() {
            navigator.notification.confirm(
            'You are the best!',  // message
            onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'TEST',            // title
            'OK'          // buttonLabels
        );
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showConfirm(); return false;">Show Confirm</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My project worked better to take the page changing out of the confirm callback, so they are separate. Like this:

```
 async showConfirm(): Promise<void> {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'You are the best!',  // message
            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            (btnId: number) => {
                    if (btnId === 1) {
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        reject();
                    },  
            },
            'TEST',            // title
            'OK'          // buttonLabels
        );
    }).then(() => {// Needed because we are navigating
        gotoSettings():
    }).catch(() => {
        // Silent
    });
```